# What does ねこ部 mean?

Tags: meaning

I see 部 with nouns in hashtags on Instagram (like #ねこ部), but I can only find dictionary definitions online. I'm also unsure of the correct reading of the kanji, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

I am not familiar with hashtags trends and what not, but it might mean they are cat lovers.

部 is usually read as ぶ and usually means department, group, division, club.
Although usually used in company jargon, this time it seems to be used to indicate that that person is in the cat group/club... maybe

Comment: The 「猫部」 translation seems to be correct: http://www.nekobu.com/

Comment: You are right. you read 部 as ぶ in this case. And 部 is often used in clubs in Japanese school like サッカー部(Succer club)、野球部(Baseball club). Obviously, ねこ部 means Cat club. It sounds like a club for cat lovers.